# How to fix poetry error 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'strict'?

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry

When I run the poetry command `poetry add isort@5.11.5` in poetry 1.1.14 on python 3.8. I see the following error:

```
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.4s)

  AttributeError

  'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'strict'

  at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cachecontrol/serialize.py:54 in dumps
       50│                 ),
       51│                 u"status": response.status,
       52│                 u"version": response.version,
       53│                 u"reason": text_type(response.reason),
    →  54│                 u"strict": response.strict,
       55│                 u"decode_content": response.decode_content,
       56│             }
       57│         }
       58│
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of it was HTTPResponse strict attribute was gone in urllib3>=2.0.0.

It is possible to fix it by installing an old version of URLLib to the venv that poetry by running `./pip install requests==2.29.0` in `~/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/bin`